# How to give read only access to a user to view the tables of different owner in oracle

Tags: oracle, permissions, schema

I have 2 users are present in oracle ex User1 and User2, Under user1 some tables are present ex t1,t2,t3 etc.. . what are the minimum permissions to view the tables of user1 by using user2 ( Just want to view the table description not the Data) .

Comment: You just want them to be able to see the table definitions & not the actual data? Why?

Comment: I wanted to create a report of tables, not with the Data and if i wanted to give access to a user to the Table definition and that user should not see the data of the table.

Answer (score 1):

The `REFERENCES` privilege kind of provides this:

```
SQL> create user u1 identified by u1;

User created.

SQL> create user u2 identified by u2;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to u1, u2;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create table to u1;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> create table u1.t1 (c1 number);

Table created.

SQL> grant references on u1.t1 to u2;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn u2/u2
Connected.
SQL> desc u1.t1
 Name           Null?     Type
 ------------------------------------
 C1                       NUMBER

SQL> select * from u1.t1;
select * from u1.t1
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my schema thousands of tables are Present. If i want to execute the above statements for each table it will take lot of time. So is there any way to grant references to all tables in my schema to another user. Thanks in Advance

Comment: @chellangisravan `begin
  for t in (select * from dba_tables where owner = 'USER1')
  loop
    execute immediate 'grant references on ' || o.owner || '.' || o.table_name || ' to USER2';
  end loop;  
end;
/`

Comment: Thank you very Much, It is working with small modification  begin for t in (select * from dba_tables where owner = 'USER1') loop execute immediate 'grant references on ' || t.owner || '.' || t.table_name || ' to USER2'; end loop; end;